# How is killing prisoners of war justified?

Tags: fiqh, sharia, non-muslim, slavery

I heard that killing male prisoners of war is allowed. How is that justified? Keep in mind that being a prisoner of war doesn’t necessarily means that you were involved in a battle. He can even be the family member of the person that fought in war against the Muslims.

Answer (score -3):

Okay. I don't know where you heard that from. The following are one's what I learned and read about war in Islam.

1. We can't attack first. If only we have valid reason,  then we can attack.
2. if someone from enemy side surrender, it's your duty to make sure, he reach his home sound and healthy.

You can always refer to Quran and hadith to find your answer in the best form. Just like from text book,  you can get the answer for your class question.

Comment: Is this what you mean by quality answer and knowledge about Islam? Well sorry this is in clear contradiction to the qur'an [8:60](https://legacy.quran.com/8/60) and shows a superficial knowledge about the qur'an, the sunnah and Islam.